# Dropdown menu hidden behind Page content, Magento 2

Tags: category-navigation, magento2menu

Before some time everything was right i dont know when it happened. Dropdown menu is hidden behind page content. Recently i've only done reindexing. I've checked z-index there isn't issue. link to website and image is attached below. Kindly have a check soon as possible. Thanks

[Link to Website](https://premiumgrocers.com)

[image: img of dropdown menu]

Answer (score 0):

I've added z-index to .nav-sections class. It solved the issue. But i was looking for the main cause..why did this happened. Looks like i am overriding any thing. That thing may be causing any other error which i dont know may be.